# Write cross-platform unit tests that handle assertions on line endings

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm using JUnit to test the printed output of a program. I'm doing this by setting `System.out` to my own `PrintStream` which prints to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. My tests usually look like this:

```
assertEquals("Some line of text\r\n", output);
```

I'm interested in how I might make this code work across platforms. If I run these tests on linux, all these tests will fail. I could write more complicated tests, which accept either `\r\n` or `\n` in the output, but I'd like to keep the tests simple if possible. Is there a way to set the type of newline printed by `println()`?

Comment: You could use a `StringBuilder` instead of using `System.setOut`

Answer (score 3):

You should keep the system's default behavior, and change your assert code:

```
String EOL = System.getProperty("line.separator")
assertEquals("Some line of text" + EOL, output);
```

Why? The EOL (end-of-line, or line-separator) is system-dependent, if you change the default behavior, you MAY meet other strange bugs.

In your case, it is enough for you to change the EOL in your own string.

Other (maybe not good) methods may include: replace all `\r\n` and `\r` to `\n` and use `\n` to compare all outputs, not use `PrintStream` but build the string by yourself, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When I write tests that need to handle multi line output, I read the output using a BufferedReader, and insert the lines into a list. Then I can assert the contents of the list line by line.

That way I don’t care what platform-specific chars the output uses for newlines because the reader is taking care of it and I’m comparing only the individual lines.

Answer (score 0):

For JUnit 4 there is the library [System Rules](https://stefanbirkner.github.io/system-rules) that helps with such kind of tests. It supports normalization of line endings, too. A test would look like

```
public class MyTest {
  @Rule
  public final SystemOutRule systemOutRule = new SystemOutRule().enableLog();

  @Test
  public void writesTextToSystemOut() {
    System.out.print(String.format("Some line of text%n)");
    assertEquals(
      "Some line of text\n",
      systemOutRule.getLogWithNormalizedLineSeparator()
    );
  }
}
```

Full Disclosure: I'm the author of System Rules.

Comment: Cool! Just the other day I was researching your library because I wanted to test calls to `System.exit()`. Unfortunately I'm using JUnit 5, and it's not available for JUnit 5 right? I was actually considering going to JUnit 4 just for that feature.